# Copy blobs between storage containers in Azure using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I wrote the following C# code for copying blobs between storage containers in Azure. It doesnt throw any error, but it doesnt give the output either.

```
static void TransferBlob(string accountName, string accountKey, string containerName, string targetContainerName)

    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(targetContainerName);
        CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob;
        CloudBlockBlob targetBlob;
        foreach (var blobItem in sourceContainer.ListBlobs())
        {
            sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobItem.Uri.ToString());
            targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobItem.Uri.ToString());
            targetBlob.StartCopy(sourceBlob);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which nuget package and version are you using for Azure Storage?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `useFlatBlobListing: true` and `blob.Name`.

```
static void TransferBlob(string accountName, string accountKey, string sourceContainerName, string targetContainerName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(sourceContainerName);
    CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(targetContainerName);
    if (sourceContainer.Exists() && targetContainer.Exists())
    {
        foreach (IListBlobItem item in sourceContainer.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
        {
            var blob = item as CloudBlockBlob;
            if (blob != null)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
                CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
                targetBlob.StartCopy(sourceBlob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```